# How to save XML file before update?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Right so I have a simple app that consists of a calendar a Set Event button and list box that populates using a DataTemplate in WPF. When I build the app the Events.xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <events>

    </events>
```

I add events to xml through code. Final structure of the xml file is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<events>
   <event Name="Some Name">
       <startDate>20.03.2010</startDate>
       <endDate>29.03.2010</endDate>
   </event>
</event>
```

Now here's my problem. If I update the app and deploy it with Click Once and the app updates it self, I lose the list because the new file is empty. Any workaround this?

Here's how I add the Data:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"Data\Events.xml");
xDocument.Root.Add(new XElement("event", new XAttribute("name", event.Name),
                new XElement("startDate", startDate),
                new XElement("endDate", endDate)
                )
                );
xDocument.Save(@"Data\Events.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an option I would suggest that you don't include the `Events.xml` as a part of the project. If you did this, you could:

1. Check to see if it is there before you load it.
2. If it is not there, write out an empty one.

If `Events.xml` is not a part of the project, Click Once won't overwrite it on updates.

Comment: if I create the file manually through code and then update the app i still lose it because the update doesn't update the .exe file. instead it creates a new folder and puts the new updated files there.

Comment: In that case I would recommend saving this Events.xml file to
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem.

Here's my method. Create a folder `@C:\Program Files\<MyApp>\Data\` add the `Events.xml` file there when the app runs for the first time and I have the file there always.

The only draw back is that user needs to delete the folder manually on uninstall.

Click Once does not install the app `@C:\Program Files\<MyApp>\` by default. It installs to `@C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\` (under Windows 7).

Any workaround this?